# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) stops when initiating class

Tags: ios, swift

I don't understand why I am getting the error "EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)"

I have no compiler errors, and this is my first time I'm getting a trap error. I have a lot of googling but I don't grasp why this happens.

I have followed the debugger frame by frame going backwards it looks like this.

Backwards --> This is the row where my debugger stops

```
**///WHEN RUNNING THIS ERROR OCCURS**
private let _userSettings =  UserSettings()
```

**I access this from**

```
static var shared: UserSettings {
        return _userSettings
    }
```

**Which is called from**

```
init() { 
             self.DisCourafeFamilyActivit = UserSettings.shared.loadData(pathToFile: LocalStoragePaths.DisCourafeFamilyActivit) ?? test
        }
```

**Which is in turn called from myModel**

```
let userSettings = UserSettings.shared
```

**TOP OF MY FILE I DO THIS**

```
let _userSettings =  UserSettings()
```

**FULL UserSettings class**

```
class UserSettings : ObservableObject {
let test = FamilyActivitySelection()

@Published var DisCourafeFamilyActivit : FamilyActivitySelection{
    
    didSet  {
        UserSettings.shared.saveData(DisCourafeFamilyActivit, pathToFile: LocalStoragePaths.DisCourafeFamilyActivit)
    }
    
}

init() { 
         self.DisCourafeFamilyActivit = UserSettings.shared.loadData(pathToFile: LocalStoragePaths.DisCourafeFamilyActivit) ?? test
    }

static var shared: UserSettings {
    return _userSettings
}

func saveData<T: Codable>(_ object: T, pathToFile: String) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.carlpalsson.superapp")
       let archiveURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(pathToFile + ".json")
       let encoder = JSONEncoder()
       if let dataToSave = try? encoder.encode(object) {
           do {
               try dataToSave.write(to: archiveURL!)
           } catch {
               // TODO: ("Error: Can't save Counters")
               return;
           }
       }
   }

func loadData<T: Codable>(pathToFile: String) -> T? {
      let documentsDirectory = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.carlpalsson.superapp")
    guard let archiveURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(pathToFile + ".json") else { return T.self as? T}
    guard let codeData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL) else {return T.self as? T}

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let decodedData = (try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: codeData)) {
                    
                    return decodedData
                }
    return T.self as? T
}
```

}

Comment: What I would do is removing lines of codes until the code runs without errors, so this way you identify the line that caused the error.

Comment: What is the benefit over simply writing `static let shared = UserSettings()`?

Comment: Where in UserSettings do you assign a value to _userSettings and where is it declared?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In the top of the file I have let _userSettings =  UserSettings()

Comment: @vadian How do I do that I new to this .. check my answer to Joakim that is how I did it now

Comment: @abv I have tried that but it breaks my implementation because properties need to be initialized

Comment: So it’s a global variable? I would recommend you research how to properly design a shared class.

Comment: As I mentioned delete the private property and write `static let shared = UserSettings()`

Comment: Look at this short [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton) from Apple on how to create a singleton which is quite similar

Comment: @vadian I did that but now the init functions has an error how do i reference the shared when i init my class? I cannot reach savedate or load data from my shared instance i tried to make them public, but I can only reach my properties

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried that approach but when running init i cannot find my methods save and loaddata

Comment: You access them using `self.loadData(...)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I really thought so but when trying to reference them in my init() they don't appear in my list?!? lf' used in method call 'loadData' before all stored properties are initialized

Comment: You could declare both functions `static` the way they are implemented and access them as UserSetting.loadData(...)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks it works!!! But my other class is complaining when trying to access the methods outside in my other class they are not in the list? How do i make them accessible outside my userSettings class. For example when doing this let _usersetting = UserSettings.shared in another class? It just says member cannot be found, but i made the methods savedata / loaddata public static func ? they shoudl be reachable?

Comment: Read my previous comment